# Substracting time from two files and write it into new files on python

Tags: python

Since I have not able to finish the last one, i still have this two files. A files containing a time that I wanted to subtract it. File A - file B and also it has a condition where from file B it need to iterate until it meet 'time' here are the files:
file A:

```
time
04:14:14.4
04:14:29.9
04:14:22.6
04:14:44.7
04:17:30.1
04:17:39.4
time
06:04:45.7
06:04:49.5
06:04:51.9
06:05:01.6
06:05:33.4
06:06:26.9
06:06:42.0
06:06:50.4
06:06:58.4
06:07:19.9
time
```

File B:

```
# 04:13:53.7
# 06:04:37.0
```

I am expecting an output simmilar to this one:

```
time
20.70
36.02
...
...
time
8.07
12.05
time
```

I have tried using a datetime on python, but I have no idea how this works. Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution, works for me:

```py
tCounter = -1
file2 = open('file2.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')

def timeToNum(time):
  timeArr = time.split(':')
  return int(timeArr[0]) * 3600 + int(timeArr[1]) * 60 + float(timeArr[2])
newFile = open('output.txt', 'w')

def addZero(num): return '0'+str(num) if float(num) < 10 else str(num)

def numToTime(num):
  return ':'.join([addZero(int(num//3600)), addZero(int(num%3600 // 60)), addZero(round(num%60,2))]);

def write(string): newFile.write(str(string)+'\n') # Just a shorthand

for line in open('file1.txt','r').read().split('\n'):
  if line == 'time':
    tCounter += 1
    write(line)
  else:
    write(numToTime(abs(timeToNum(line) - timeToNum(file2[tCounter]))))
newFile.close()
```

I actually didn't use `datetime` at all, also you can replace the file names :)

Comment: any idea what happened? here is the current output:
...
      4 def timeToNum(time):
      5   timeArr = time.split(':')
----> 6   return int(timeArr[0]) * 3600 + int(timeArr[1]) * 60 + float(timeArr[2])

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '# Time'

Comment: Oh just remove the `#` (and the space), so line 1 in file2 will be `04:13:53.7`.

Comment: I do not know what happened but it still outputting the same result: 
     19     write(line)
     20   else:
...
      4 def timeToNum(time):
      5   timeArr = time.split(':')
----> 6   return int(timeArr[0]) * 3600 + int(timeArr[1]) * 60 + float(timeArr[2])

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Hmm... Did you delete the `#` and the space in line 2 as well?  It works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: You're welcome, hope it works :)